# JSON parse from a Remote URL which requires a username and password

Tags: json, rest, authentication, basic-authentication

I have a url which points to a JSON output, however this URL requires a username and password through a standard apache pop up authentication box. I have tried to access this URL from my rails controller like the following:

```
result = JSON.parse(open("http://user:pass@myurl.com/json").read)
```

However it isn't working. 
I have the following at the top of my controller:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
```

I just get an error which says `ArgumentError, userinfo not supported. [RFC3986]`

Comment: why do you think it's not working ? any error?

Comment: Yea I just get an error which says ArgumentError, userinfo not supported.  [RFC3986]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to  password and user as additional option

```
 open("http://...", :http_basic_authentication=>[user, password])
```

Comment: What about a digest auth?