# Ruby open "userinfo not supported": URL with basic auth

Tags: ruby, ftp, basic-authentication

I have a lot of URLs in the following format

- ftp://user:pass@example.com/some_image.jpg
- https://user:pass@example.com/some_image.jpg

When I try to load the image with ruby's `open` method, it throws the following error for `https`, but works for `ftp`

```
open(URI.parse("ftp://user:pass@example.com/some_image.jpg")) # works
open(URI.parse("https://user:pass@example.com/some_image.jpg")) # throws error:

# ArgumentError: userinfo not supported.  [RFC3986]
```

I found ([JSON parse from a Remote URL which requires a username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520488/json-parse-from-a-remote-url-which-requires-a-username-and-password)) that you can provide `open` with basic auth parameter like this

```
url = URI.parse(url)
open(url, http_basic_authentication: [url.user,url.password])
```

But this still throws the error, because the url contains still the user / password info.

So, what would be an easy way to parse out the user / password info from the url? I tried it by concatenating the parts of the URL by myself like this:

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
uri_base = "#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}:#{uri.port}#{uri.path}"
uri_base += "?#{uri.query}" if uri.query
open(uri_base, http_basic_authentication: [uri.user,uri.password])
```

But this doesn't work for FTP, it throws an `Net::FTPPermError: 530 User _ftp denied by SACL.` error.

> So is there an easy way to support `open` with **optional** http basic authentication for `https` AND `ftp`?

**Update**

I came up with the following solution, but it looks kinda hacky, and I think there must be a better way:

```
  def download url
    opts = {}
    uri = URI.parse(url)

    uri_base = "#{uri.scheme}://"
    if uri.scheme=="ftp"
      uri_base += "#{uri.user}:#{uri.password}@" if uri.user
    else
      opts[:http_basic_authentication] = [uri.user,uri.password] if uri.user
    end
    uri_base += "#{uri.host}:#{uri.port}/#{uri.path}"
    uri_base += "?#{uri.query}" if uri.query
    open(uri_base, opts)
  end
```